# content byte has strange colour behaviour with 5.5.5 jar

Tags: itext, itextpdf

I have code which has worked for some time to stamp 'DRAFT' over the pages of a PDF file
I just updated the app to the 5.5.5 jar and for some PDFs instead of lovely pink watermark it is only black. The code works properly for both source files with 5.5.3, and not for the second with 5.5.4 as the second source is tagged (due to the background letterhead file - issue introduced which throws a NullPointerError) and now not with 5.5.5 either (no error but undesired result)

It works with a simple 'hello world' example but not other files created from iText
file eg_01 and eg_o1A show working example, 1B and 1C show not working example

Stamping code snippet in Groovy

```
import com.itextpdf.text.Element
import com.itextpdf.text.BaseColor
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamper
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader

today = new Date()
reader = new PdfReader(source)
stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(output))
bf = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_BOLD, BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED)
tSize = 24
mark = 'DRAFT ' + today.format('dd/MM/yyyy')
angle = 45
height = reader.getPageSizeWithRotation(1).getHeight()/2
width = reader.getPageSizeWithRotation(1).getWidth()/2
cb = stamper.getOverContent(1)
cb.setColorFill(new BaseColor(255,200,200))
cb.setFontAndSize(bf, tSize)
cb.beginText()
cb.showTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_CENTER, mark, width.toFloat(), height.toFloat(), angle)
cb.endText()
stamper.close()
reader.close()
return true
```

Comment: Are the non working files all tagged?

Comment: Yes, apologies for not linking to examples https://www.dropbox.com/s/befn0eu6pe58paz/eg_01.pdf?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/mr2ihz2pulncxh7/eg_01A.pdf?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/bfbtvh8t1sgoub1/eg_01B.pdf?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ai9nhtj7pzyt5sq/eg_01C.pdf?dl=0

Comment: The background artwork file is output as tagged by default form InDesign, over which I have no control, which seems to make any intermediate files tagged to. In this case example B is created by putting the text over the background with iText, and then has the draft stamped after the creation event

Comment: As it is tagged, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29094269/1729265) and move the `cb.setColorFill(new BaseColor(255,200,200))` after the `cb.beginText()`.

Comment: mkl... thanks for link to extensive answer.. however does not work with the example B files

Comment: I'll look into that sample.

Comment: I just tested your issue, cf. [StampColoredText.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/stamp/StampColoredText.java) with both iText 5.5.5 and 5.5.6-SNAPSHOT. After moving the `cb.setColorFill(new BaseColor(255,200,200))` after the `cb.beginText()`, it worked, even for the B file.

Comment: mkl - thanks for the troubleshooting on this..  I just rebooted and everything is as you experience sit here, so work round fixes the issue. Can the API documentation be amended to reflect this behaviour?

Comment: I'm not sure this behavior is desirable at all. So they'll maybe change it. If they don't change it, though, they of course shall document this quirk.

Comment: Thanks! I've created a support ticket for this. (I'm gearing up for the ISO committee meeting; I've been working on the dig sig section all day.)

Comment: Ticket [DEV-1371](https://jira.itextsupport.com/browse/DEV-1371) has just been closed as "Fixed". The fix will be in 5.5.6 (due in the next couple of days).